# android two-way Data Binding - data changes does not update UI views

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, 2-way-object-databinding

I am using android two-way data binding, but data changes does not update view elements. I have a simple string correctly displayed on an TextInputEditText, but when the bound viewmodel livedata variable is updated, the view is not updating. The variable **info** is supposed to show 'Hello my friend' on the radiobutton click listener..but it is not updating the ui.

fragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private MainViewModel mViewModel;
private MainFragmentBinding mDataBinding;

public static MainFragment newInstance() {
    return new MainFragment();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
    return mDataBinding.getRoot();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);

    mViewModel.getInfo().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), info -> {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "First in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    });

    mDataBinding.radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mViewModel.getInfo().setValue("Hello my friend");
        }
    });

    mDataBinding.setViewModel(mViewModel);
}
}
```

viewmodel:

```
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {

private MutableLiveData<String> info;

public MutableLiveData<String> getInfo() {
    if (info == null) {
        info = new MutableLiveData<>();
        info.setValue("First Info Initialization");
    }

    return info;
}

public void setInfo(String info) {
    this.info.setValue(info);
}
```

and view is something like:

```
    <layout>...
    <data>

        <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.example.temp.ui.main.MainViewModel" />
    </data>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Info"
            android:text="@={viewModel.info}" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </layout>
```

Comment: I found the solution. The activity hosting the fragment was the one bound to the binding class lyfecycle. The solution updated on the problem above

Answer (score 1):

To use a LiveData object with your binding class, you need to specify a lifecycle owner to define the scope of the LiveData object.

```
// Specify the current activity as the lifecycle owner.
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

The binding lifecycle owner was the Activity hosting the fragment:

```
MainActivityBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main_activity);
binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
```

Then I had to remove it and set the Fragment as the lifecycle owner.

Answer (score 0):

While using  Data Binding, you should take care of two things.

1. Assign ViewModel to a variable that is defined under your layout tag in the xml:

```
binding.vm = yourViewModel
```

(Note: `vm` is a variable name that you defined under layout tag.)

2. Most important, provide lifecycleOwner to your binding class:

```
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
```